# Retrieving name attribute from Scala Enumeration Value

Tags: scala

I have created a Scala Enumeration as follows:

```
object TimerStatus extends Enumeration {
    type Status = Value
    val InProgress = Value(1, "Pause Timer")
    val Paused = Value(-1, "Resume Timer")  
}
```

I then have a Match class that contains TimerStatus as a member

How is it possible to retieve the "Pause Timer" or "Resume Timer" text from my enumeration Values?

I can retrieve the id using `myMatch.timerStatus.id` but I don't see any way to get the `name`

If not possible, what is best workaround?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.toString` [method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L221) returns the `name`.

Comment: OK, I had thought that might not work when I read its implementation here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration$Val I will try that so

Comment: `.id` returns the integer id and `.toString` returns the literal name.